# variable only set at end of FOR loop and then lingering on next run

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I have a file `file.txt` that looks like this:

```
string1a,string1b
string2a,string2b
string3a,string3b
```

I am trying to run the following batch file:

```
@echo off
For /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in ("file.txt") do (
echo The output is:
echo %%a
echo %%b
set var_1=%%a
echo %var_1%
echo %var_1:~6%
set var_2=%%b
echo %var_2%
echo %var_2:~6%
)
```

When I run it the first time, the result is:

```
The output is:
string1a
string1b
ECHO is off.
~6
ECHO is off.
~6
The output is:
string2a
string2b
ECHO is off.
~6
ECHO is off.
~6
The output is:
string3a
string3b
ECHO is off.
~6
ECHO is off.
~6
```

When I run it a second time, the result is:

```
The output is:
string1a
string1b
string3a
3a
string3b
3b
The output is:
string2a
string2b
string3a
3a
string3b
3b
The output is:
string3a
string3b
string3a
3a
string3b
3b
```

If I then change the last line of `file.txt` to:

```
string3x,string3y
```

and run the batch file again, the result is:

```
The output is:
string1a
string1b
string3a
3a
string3b
3b
The output is:
string2a
string2b
string3a
3a
string3b
3b
The output is:
string3x
string3y
string3a
3a
string3b
3b
```

If I then run the batch file again the result is:

```
The output is:
string1a
string1b
string3x
3x
string3y
3y
The output is:
string2a
string2b
string3x
3x
string3y
3y
The output is:
string3x
string3y
string3x
3x
string3y
3y
```

Can anybody explain what's going on here? The result I'm expecting in the first place is:

```
The output is:
string1a
string1b
string1a
1a
string1b
1b
The output is:
string2a
string2b
string2a
2a
string2b
2b
The output is:
string3a
string3b
string3a
3a
string3b
3b
```

Somehow the variable doesn't seem to get set until the third iteration of the `FOR` loop, and then it lingers on in the next run of batch file. I'm trying to set `var_1` and `var_2` in each iteration to the values of `%%a` and `%%b` in that current iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to lie in [enabling delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), so batch file should be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
For /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in ("file.txt") do (
echo The output is:
echo %%a
echo %%b
set var_1=%%a
echo !var_1!
echo !var_1:~6!
set var_2=%%b
echo !var_2!
echo !var_2:~6!
)
```